# How to lemmatize strings in pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, spacy, lemmatization

I have a Python Pandas dataframe, where I need to lemmatize the words in two of the columns. I am using using spacy for this.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en")
```

I am trying to use lemmatization based on this example (which works perfectly fine):

```
doc3 = nlp(u"this is spacy lemmatize testing. programming books are more better than others")
for token in doc3: 
    print (token, token.lemma, token.lemma_)
```

I have rewritten this to loop through each row of one of the columns in my dataframe:

```
for row in example['col1']:
    for token in row:
        print(token.lemma_)
```

This works, however, I have not been able to figure out how to replace the words in col1 with the lemmatized words.

I have tried this, which does not return an error, but also does not replace any words. Any idea what is going wrong?

```
for row in example['col1']:
    for token in row:
        token = token.lemma_
```

Answer (score 8):

In the last `for` loop of your code, you are repeatedly assigning to the variable `token` its attribute `token.lemma_` and then doing this again and again (overwriting this at every iteration and not keeping track of the previous values).

Instead, assuming that your dataframe contains strings, as in

```
example = pd.DataFrame({"col1":["this is spacy lemmatization testing.", "some programming books are better than others", "sounds like a quote from the Smiths"]})
```

`apply` and list comprehensions can do the job with:

```
example["col1"].apply(lambda row: " ".join([w.lemma_ for w in nlp(row)]))
```