# How can I lemmatize a tokenized column of a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nltk, lemmatization

I try to lemmatize the column "tokenized" in a dataframe. One cell of the column "tokenized" looks as follows *"  yeah    simply    zurich    generic    serving    think    media    bland    prepared    curry    kind    paying    well    loves    used    parboiled    oily    place    elaborate    non    tasteful    stay    underspiced    institution    vegetarian    indian    clueless    away    hiltl    anyone    served    support    veg    long    like    normal    strong    worth    insult    not    rice    kitchen    know    wont    food    cuisine    fantastic    fan    time    term    patrons  ".*

**When I run my code it returns something like this: ",,e,n,d,e,d,,,p,a,y,i"** which is not what i want. How can I lemmatize full words?

This is my code:

```
reviews_english['tokenized_lem'] = reviews_english['tokenized'].apply(
                    lambda lst:[lmtzr.lemmatize(word) for word in lst])
reviews_english
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your "tokenized" column doesn't look ready to apply the lemmatization step, as it contains a string, not a list of tokens. In other words, instead of having

```
" yeah simply zurich generic serving ..."
```

you should have in your dataframe `tokenized` cell a list of tokens (generated with a tokenizer from your initial sentence), as in

```
["yeah", "simply", "zurich", "generic", "serving", ...]
```

If you don't have a proper list of tokens in your dataframe cell, python will iterate in your `apply`/`lambda` list comprehension character by character, which is clearly not what you want.

Comment: For an example using spaCy to do the task, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498293/how-can-i-lemmatize-strings-in-pandas-dataframes/49322360#49322360